# How to increase the height of a view in Android Layout dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

How to extend the height of the separated vertical line (view) dynamically in the image?

This is the XML I'm using:

```
<View android:layout_width="1dp" 
      android:layout_height="100dp" 
      android:id="@+id/view_verdict" 
      android:background="@color/line"             
      android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: post the xml maybe?

Comment: <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/view_verdict"
                android:background="@color/line"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

Comment: i meant the hole xml. it is just the divider. i need to see the wrapper

Comment: And post it as an edit not in comments

Comment: I have added my xml code too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your XML into your question. However, the question is not yet up to our standards. Since you want to change the height dynamically, you should show what Java code you have tried; a [mcve] is best. I have inlined your images, but in general a picture of code is not received well here. You should really remove the first picture and replace it with the relevant parts of your XML. I cannot do this, as I do not know how relevant it is to your own attempts.

Comment: By the way - you can use the "edit" link below your question to edit it. Or just click it here: [edit]. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example code will be useful (I suppose that your view is a LinearLayout):

```
    final int newHeight = 100; //this is the new height will be set in your view
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newHeight);//first param is the width, and second the height
    myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Or just put:

```
...
android:layout_height="match_parent"
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gaston Flores. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Is there other solution possible?

Comment: Yes there is a solution, I can´t in this moment, maybe in a few hours. Thanks

Comment: @Sudheer Did you try to replace android:layout_height="100dp" with android:layout_height="match_parent"?

Answer (score 0):

set

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for your view with id `view_verdict`